# Checkbox checked or not cannot be logged

Tags: android

I am an android learner, I have a task from my course to write into the log when a checkbox is clicked.
My XML is:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/whippedCreamCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Whipped Cream"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:paddingLeft ="24dp"
    android:buttonTint="#008000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
```

And corresponding java code is

```
public void indicateBoxChecked(View v) {
        CheckBox whippedCreamCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.whippedCreamCheckBox);
        boolean checked = whippedCreamCheckBox.isChecked();
        Log.v(TAG, "Checkbox value is " + checked );
    }
```

The remaining code builds, runs and functions without errors. However, in the log I cannot see the desired output. But I see

> Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 4798584 , only
>   wrote 4798080

You can access the entire log here https://gist.github.com/latrociny/f318f74bbf9b9e28cc0a3a5370eaf996

Comment: when is this function called? on checkbox click?

Comment: No I did not create any other function to call this. Should I create another method to call this method?

Comment: You should call this function or otherwise how will you reach log printing statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this attribute to the `CheckBox`:

```
android:onClick="indicateBoxChecked"
```

and change your code to this (it is inside your activity class isn't it?):

```
public void indicateBoxChecked(View v) {
    CheckBox whippedCreamCheckBox = (CheckBox) v;
    boolean checked = whippedCreamCheckBox.isChecked();
    Log.v(TAG, "Checkbox value is " + checked );
}
```

now whenever you click the `CheckBox`, the method `indicateBoxChecked()` will be executed.  
I guess the variable `TAG` has been initialized.

Comment: Can you please tell why did you not do CheckBox whippedCreamCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.whippedCreamCheckBox); ?

yes it is inside activity class and TAG is initialized

Comment: @Kay so now you see the log message?

Comment: @Kay you don't need findViewById because the parameter `v` is the clicked View.

Comment: @Kay you just have to cast `v` to a `CheckBox`

Comment: hi this is fixed, thanks. I see now 2018-11-20 18:02:13.819 8019-8019/com.example.android.justjava V/MainActivity: Checkbox value is true
2018-11-20 18:02:27.220 8019-8019/com.example.android.justjava V/MainActivity: Checkbox value is false
2018-11-20 18:02:28.943 8019-8019/com.example.android.justjava V/MainActivity: Checkbox value is true